# A finitely presented module over a finitely presented algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R\rightarrow S$ be a finitely presented homomorphism of rings and $M$ a finitely presented $S$-module.

My question: if $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module, then is $M$ also finitely presented over $R$?

The special case when $M=S$ is [EGA IV1, 1.4.7]: any finite finitely presented algebra is finitely presented as a module.